Get index set dimension names from constructed constraint
Given this set and constraint definition
index_set_a = pyo.Set(
    initialize=[(p, j) for p in model.Units for j in model.YEARS if model.check_year[p] <= j]
)

model.a = pyo.Constraint(index_set_a, rule=rule_a)

is it possible to access the set's "dimension names", i.e. "Units" and "YEARS", from model.a.index_set(), e.g. for output purposes to print dual values and having telling names for index positions?
Note: Doing output processing of pyomo Vars the equivalent names I am after are available in the var.index_set.subsets() list and the .name property for each list element which correspond to the "dimension names".
Edit: When I try with this:
index_set_a = pyo.Set(
    model.InstallableUnits,
    model.YEARS,
    initialize=[(p, j) for p in model.Units for j in model.YEARS if model.check_year[p] <= j]
)

I get the error:
Cannot apply a Set operator to an indexed Set component (IndexedSet)
Edit 2: For illustration, this is the approach I use for Vars that I mentioned and that I wanted to adapt to constraints (and their duals).
import pyomo.environ as pyo

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

m.Units = pyo.Set(initialize=["a", "b"])
m.YEARS = pyo.Set(initialize=[2024, 2025])

m.x = pyo.Var(
    m.Units,
    m.YEARS,
    domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals,
)
index_set = m.x.index_set()
for subset in index_set.subsets():
    print(subset.name)

which outputs:
Units
YEARS


Try setting the domain when making the crossed set.  This also has the added benefit of QA'ing your data as it is brought into the set--although there is little risk of problem as you are constructing it directly now.
Going the next step and "peeling" the individual set names back out of that...probably not advised, but doable.  You might need to troll around some of the pyomo internals to find what you want.  But setting the domain at least makes things clear with pprint() or display().
In [22]: import pyomo.environ as pyo

In [23]: m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

In [24]: m.years = pyo.Set(initialize=[1999, 2000])

In [25]: m.animals = pyo.Set(initialize=['horse', 'cat'])

In [26]: m.zodiac = pyo.Set(domain=m.years * m.animals, initialize=((y, a) for y in m.years for a in m.animals))

In [27]: 

In [27]: m.zodiac.pprint()
zodiac : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
    Key  : Dimen : Domain        : Size : Members
    None :     2 : years*animals :    4 : {(1999, 'horse'), (1999, 'cat'), (2000, 'horse'), (2000, 'cat')}

In [28]: m.zodiac._domain
Out[28]: <pyomo.core.base.set.SetProduct_OrderedSet at 0x107e23840>

...

In [31]: _28.__str__()
Out[31]: 'years*animals'

=============
Another (easier) alternative is just to use the doc:
In [12]: import pyomo.environ as pyo

In [13]: m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

In [14]: m.zodiac = pyo.Set(initialize=((y, a) for y in [1990, 2000] for a in ['horse', 'dog']), doc='year - animal')

In [15]: m.zodiac.name
Out[15]: 'zodiac'

In [16]: m.zodiac.doc
Out[16]: 'year - animal'

In [17]: m.pprint()
1 Set Declarations
    zodiac : year - animal
        Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    Any :    4 : {(1990, 'horse'), (1990, 'dog'), (2000, 'horse'), (2000, 'dog')}

1 Declarations: zodiac


Thanks for your suggestion, explanation and example code. My use case is exactly the "peeling" the individual set names back out of that. My "trolling" did not lead me anywhere, hence my question here. So do you mean that setting the domain is a necessary step to enable the "peeling", i.e. respective internals (that I tried without it) are only usable with that?

@phaebz. I don't know any more detail than provided.  Honestly, I think you are at risk of making code that is rather complex/fragile for little benefit.  Have you considered just using the doc feature?  (Shown in edit)

please see the "Edit 2" in OP where I show how I do this for Vars. It is neither complex nor fragile and has a lot of benefits with respect to our output processing - which benefits from the context of index set names. I hoped I could use a similar approach for constraints. Thanks for the .doc approach, it is a good fallback to have, but that field is already taken in our model implementation and would need more parsing logic for the set name parts and more code changes in total. I would like to minimize changes to the existing model.
